# How to make 'Outside' print to the console only after printing 'Yes'/'No' in Angular 10

Tags: html, angular, typescript

app.component.html contains a button which when clicked executes the code under openConfirmationDialog method.
Inside this method I am getting Outside printed first and then only based on the user selection from the dialog box 'Yes' or 'No' is being printed on the console.

How to make 'Yes'/'No' being printed to the console prior to 'Outside'?
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IglYe.png)

**app.component.html:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openConfirmationDialog()">Click</button>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from './confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){

  }
  openConfirmationDialog(){
    this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      disableClose: false
    }).afterClosed().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        if(data){
          console.log('yes');
        }
        else{
          console.log('no');
        }
      }
    );

    console.log('Outside');
}

}
```

**confirmation-dialog.component.html:**

```
<h1 md-dialog-title>Confirm</h1>
<div md-dialog-content>{{confirmMessage}}</div>
<div md-dialog-actions>
  <button md-button style="color: #fff;background-color: #153961;" (click)="dialogRef.close(true)">Confirm</button>
  <button md-button (click)="dialogRef.close(false)">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**confirmation-dialog.component.ts**

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'confirm-dialog',
  templateUrl: './confirmation-dialog.component.html',
})
export class ConfirmationDialogComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmationDialogComponent>) {}

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  public confirmMessage:string='';
}
```

Comment: Can I know the reason as to why you want to display `Outside` after `Yes/No`, knowing the use-case/flow would help me answer it in a better way.

Comment: @HassanMoin I want the flow to be executed line after line. In this case "Yes/No" is before "Outside".

Comment: Please refer to the answer I posted, you can not run it line by line as you are using a function that is `async`  in nature.

Comment: @HassanMoin that worked. But is there any solution other than finalize. Say for example if there are 100 lines in place of console.log('Outside') and I want those 100 lines to be executed only after all lines inside subscribe are executed. I cannot place all those 100 lines inside finalize. Is there are other solution?

Comment: You can just create a separate function with those 100 lines, and simply call that function in `finalize` to do that work for you. `finalize(()=> this.myHugeFunction( ) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the RxJs operator `finalize` to run your code after `Yes` or `No`
The operator `finalize` will call your function after the observable completes or errors

Your code will look something like this:

```
openConfirmationDialog(): void {
        this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, { disableClose: false })
            .afterClosed()
            .pipe(finalize(() => console.log('Outside')))
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                if (data) {
                    console.log('yes');
                } else {
                    console.log('no');
                }
            });
        console.log('Not Async so it will always run before Yes or No');
    }
```

**Note** that the `console.log` outside the `subscription` will always run before `yes`, `no`, or `Outside` because the `subscribe` code block is `async`

The output would be like this:

[image]